# Postgresql select 5 rows even if there is 3 row of data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How to Select 5 row even if there is 3 row of data and next 2 row should be empty row.

Comment: You cannot return rows that are not there.

Comment: For questions like these, please remember to post the table structure, some sample of the data you have, and your expected result.

Comment: 1 col1 col2
2              
3

Comment: @JossyJoy Edit your question with the additional data and then comment so other now you add  more info. To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: I used this to resolve the issue of detail band in Jasper Ireport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union the result with *empty rows*, which should have the same types of columns as the table. Example:

```
with my_table(id, str, a_date) as (
values
    (1, 'first', '2017-09-01'::date),
    (2, 'second', '2017-09-02'),
    (3, 'third', '2017-09-03')
)

select *
from my_table

union all

select null::int, null::text, null::date
from generate_series(1, 5) -- generate 5 empty rows

order by id nulls last
limit 5

 id |  str   |   a_date   
----+--------+------------
  1 | first  | 2017-09-01
  2 | second | 2017-09-02
  3 | third  | 2017-09-03
    |        | 
    |        | 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Nice. didnt know you could remove the SELECT to get the inline dataset.

Comment: I used this to resolve the issue of detail band in Jasper Ireport.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with 5 numbers, then you assign a row number to your table and perform a left join.

The cte are the data, then at the end is the query need it:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/VAEU14734)**

```
WITH all5 as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS t (ID)
), some2 as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('first'), ('second')) AS t (value)
)
SELECT * 
FROM all5
LEFT JOIN (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value) as rn, *
           FROM some2) as t
  ON all5.ID = t.rn
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]